# How do I start subflow in a workflow in APEX Workflows?

Tags: oracle-apex

I was wondering how can I start a subflow execution in a workflow? In the workflow designer, I noticed I can only use 1 Start element, but many End elements. Is there a way I can start a workflow execution using an API call (like I can create tasks and manipulate with them using the APEX_APPROVAL API programatically)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this today by creating a process-type plugin (custom
plugin), and define an execute function and complete function in it.

1. The exec function should call apex_workflow.start_worfklow with the
   static id of the sub-workflow you have and pass in the necessary
   parameters.
2. You can define the parameters using the custom
   attributes of the process plugin.
3. The complete function should just return the complete_result as success.  Check the checkbox for Wait For Completion attribute in your custom plugin.
4. In the parent workflow, use this custom plugin as a workflow activity.
5. In your subworkflow define the last activity as execute code and
   call apex_workflow.continue_activity passing the instance id of the
   parent workflow instance and the static id of the activity you defined in step 4.

This way, at runtime, when your subworkflow completes it will
continue the parent workflow.

Could you post this question on forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community? Then I could elaborate more on the exact code for the execution and completion functions of the process type plugin.

Thanks, Ananya